# Hyperledger Composer Rest Server : After authentication, authorisation on basis of acl

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

The tutorial on OAuth [here](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/google_oauth2_rest) describes how to authenticate a client of composer-rest-server. After logging in, the client manually selects the default identity.
Is it possible to identify who the participant is from his email ID and setting it to default identity? For example, if alice@somenetwork.com [a trader] authenticates using OAuth, acl of trader are set automatically and her identity is set to default. If some other user logs in, his/her identity is set by default rather than the user choosing / having the right to choose the default identity after logging in.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If alice987@gmail.com authenticates with the REST server, and then imports a card 'AliceTrader' and sets is as default.

When bob789@gmail.com authenticates with the REST server, he **does not** see the same Wallet as Alice.  He has to import his own card and set to default.

If Alice and Bob have only 1 card in their wallets it will be the default.

In a production scenario, users won't be directly accessing the REST server, your client program will do that and so you can programatically set the defaults if you wish to.